# How to use 'this' pointer with smart pointers

Tags: c++, this, smart-pointers, weak-ptr

I have a static function where I pass a collider and the other collider is itself. I used a regular pointer before and changed it to `shared_ptr`. I can't find a solution to how I can pass this as a shared pointer. Everytime I do something it seems it deletes itself inside the function.

```
bool RectCollider::CheckCollision(std::shared_ptr<Collider> other, Vector3& normal, float& depth) {
    
    std::shared_ptr<RectCollider> otherRect = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<RectCollider>(other);
    std::weak_ptr<RectCollider> thisGo = std::shared_ptr<RectCollider>(this);
    if (otherRect) {
        
        if (otherRect == thisGo.lock()) 
            return false;
        return Collision::RectCollision(thisGo.lock(), otherRect, normal, depth);
    }

    std::shared_ptr<CircleCollider> otherCircle = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<CircleCollider>(other);
    if (otherCircle) {
        return Collision::CircleRectCollision(thisGo.lock(), otherCircle, normal, depth);
    }

    return false;
}
```

I'm sure `thisGo` is the problem.

I trid to use ChatGPT and it gave me this code and `shared_from_this` but it doesn't work.

Comment: `class CircleCollider;
class RectCollider : std::enable_shared_from_this<RectCollider>, public Collider {
public:

    //...
};`

I added enable_shared_from_this and used it like: `std::shared_ptr<RectCollider> thisGo = std::shared_from_this();` and I Itried to do it with `weak_ptr`

Comment: It seems that you may be having a conceptual problem with what `std::shared_ptr` really is, and how it works. Can you explain, in your own words, what you believe that `std::shared_ptr` is, and why it is necessary to create one from `this`. What problem would that solve?

Comment: You aren't doing anything with the shared pointers themselves (e.g. storing them for later), just accessing what they point to. So just replace all the shared pointers in the code you've shown us with regular (possibly const) references

Comment: thank you for helping, I figured out what's wrong myself this how I fixed the script `bool RectCollider::CheckCollision(std::shared_ptr<Collider> other, Vector3& normal, float& depth) {
    
    std::shared_ptr<RectCollider> otherRect = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<RectCollider>(other);
    std::shared_ptr<Collider> sharedThis = shared_from_this();
    if (otherRect) { ///.....
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you for helping, I figured out what's wrong myself this how I fixed the script

```
bool RectCollider::CheckCollision(std::shared_ptr<Collider> other, Vector3& normal, float& depth) {
    
    std::shared_ptr<RectCollider> otherRect = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<RectCollider>(other);
    std::shared_ptr<Collider> sharedThis = shared_from_this();
    if (otherRect) {
        
        if (otherRect == sharedThis) 
            return false;
        return Collision::RectCollision(sharedThis, otherRect, normal, depth);
    }

    std::shared_ptr<CircleCollider> otherCircle = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<CircleCollider>(other);
    if (otherCircle) {
        return Collision::CircleRectCollision(sharedThis, otherCircle, normal, depth);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Please format your code properly as you did in the question

Answer (score 0):

[`std::shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) has a reference counter, that is, it tracks how many `std::shared_ptr` instances point to the same object. Each time a `std::shared_ptr` goes out of scope, the counter gets decremented. If it reaches 0, then the object pointed to will be deallocated.

Lets look at a simple example:

```
#include <memory>

class Obj {
public:
    Obj() {
        std::shared_ptr<Obj>(this);
    }
};

int main() {
    Obj o;

    return 0;
}
```

When constructing our `Obj`, we create a temporary `std::shared_ptr<Obj>`. It will get created, the reference counter gets 1, then (since its temporary) it gets destroyed right again and the reference counter gets decremented to 0. This means that the temporary will try to `delete` our object via the `this` pointer. But `this` was not allocated via `new` and `delete`-ing memory which was not acquired via `new` is UB (undefined behavior).

To avoid this deletion you can supply the `std::shared_ptr` constructor with a custom deleter. This deleter will be called (when the refernce counter reaches 0) instead of a plain `delete`. If you wrap the `this` pointer via a `std::shared_ptr` you probably don't want any deallocation to go on so the deleter can be left empty and you could wrap it in a function like the following:

```
template <typename T>
std::shared_ptr<T> makeThisShared(T* that) {
    return std::shared_ptr<T>(that, [](T*) {});
}
```

Comment: This explains the issue but doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Note that if you really want a `std::shared_ptr` that is not reference counted then using the aliasing constructor is a better option. e.g. `std::shared_ptr<Obj> pThis(std::shared_ptr<Obj>(), this);` in this case. This creates a shared ptr without control block, and therefore no reference count nor deleter => it behaves like a bare pointer. (and also completely avoids the control block allocation) [godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/eze446EK5)